# Eclipse Conditional-Breakpoint. How to check if exception occurs?

Tags: java, eclipse, conditional-breakpoint

I have this function:

```
public static FradId readFradId(DataInput pIn) throws IOException {
    Integer lMainId = Integer.valueOf(pIn.readInt());
    Integer lReferenceId = Integer.valueOf(pIn.readInt());
    String lShortname = pIn.readUTF();
    return new FradId(lMainId,lReferenceId,lShortname);
  }
```

I got a breakpoint at this line:

```
String lShortname = pIn.readUTF();
```

my problem is in some cases the function `readUTF` throws a `RuntimeException`. The application executes the function more than 100 times so it is very difficult for me finding the problem.

my question: is there a way to catch that exception with a breakpoint condition? I already use that conditions with easy boolean conditions, but I dont know how to stop in that line when a exception is thrown.

Thx in advance

Stefan

Comment: That why catch clause is there, place break point in catch clause and your method should be surrounded by try catch

Comment: I see no reason to surround it with a try-catch. I have to determine the reason for the RuntimeException. If I include the try-catch in this class I would implement around the real problem. Sure for that one testcase I could include the try-catch but I hope that this is also possible with a conditional breakpoint.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes there is a option called  "exception breakpoint"
Open Breakpoint view, click on `j!` option and add desired exception

[image]

Comment: That works, but it can result in a lot of false positives. Is there a way to break when an exception is thrown by a certain line, or within a certain function?

Comment: in such case you can directly set breakpoint on that particular line and check if exception is thrwon or  not

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [Java Exception Break Point](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/breakpoints/ref-addexception_viewaction.htm)

In you eclipse open the '*Add Java Exception Breakpoint...*' from *Run* Menu. You can chose the exception for which you need to have the breakpoint.

```
Run -> Add Java Exception Breakpoint...
```

Answer (score 1):

did you try something similar?

```
public static FradId readFradId(DataInput pIn) throws IOException {
    Integer lMainId = Integer.valueOf(pIn.readInt());
    Integer lReferenceId = Integer.valueOf(pIn.readInt());
    try{
        String lShortname = pIn.readUTF();
    }catch(Exception e){
       //need a breakpoint here.
    }
    return new FradId(lMainId,lReferenceId,lShortname);
}
```